# linearHypothesis command not showing the f test values

Tags: linear-regression, dummy-variable, linearhypothesis

This is what I am trying to do test the null hypothesis that geographic regions jointly do not matter for earnings.

Here is my unrestricted regression

ftest1 <- lmrob(log(df$wage)~ df$educ + df$northeast + df$midwest + df$south)

This is the code that is not giving me the f stest

linearHypothesis(ftest1, c("df$northeast + df$midwest + df$south = 0"))

[image: code output]

I was expecting the f test but instead got the chisquared test